# How to check if a batch passed parameter exists?

Tags: batch-file

How could I modify the following example code to check if the input parameter was given when starting the batch file?

Because the check `IF NOT %MYDIR%==test` fails and terminates the batch process if no paramter was provided.

```
SET MYDIR=%1

IF {no parameter given} OR NOT %MYDIR%==test (
   ECHO dir is not "test"
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is surprisingly difficult to handle all possibilities when dealing with passed parameters. But the following strategy works under most "ordinary" situations.

```
if "%~1" equ "" echo arg 1 was not passed
```

It is important that the `~` modifier is used because you have no way of knowing if the passed argument is already enclosed in quotes. If an argument like `"this&that"` is passed and you don't first remove the quotes before adding your own, then you get `if ""this&that"" equ ""`. The `&` is no longer quoted and your command no longer parses properly.

Answer (score 0):

Strings cannot be completely empty, a common way to work around this constraint is to enclose strings in quotes like this

```
... OR NOT "%MYDIR%"=="test"
```

or you can add something meaningless without enclosing the string (ugly!)

```
... OR NOT XXX%MYDIR%==XXXtest
```